# update data based on the difference from previous data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two table named `curtest` and `prevtest`

`prevtest` has following data:

```
data    value
pen      10
book     20
```

`curtest` has following data:

```
data    value
book    30
```

if `curtest` has the data different from the last row of  `prevtest` than insert `curtest` data in the `prevtest` table so `prevtest` data will be:

```
data   value
pen    10
book   20
book   30
```

there are 20 columns in the table. if data of any one or set of columns changes then i need to insert the `curtest` data in `prevtest` table, otherwise leave as it is.

NOTE : signature of both the tables will always be same.

How to write sql query for this. any help would be much appreciated. thanks.

Comment: i  am using postgresql.

Comment: do you have any "date" column also in your tables?

Comment: yes date column is there in the table.

Comment: in that case do you want to update ( you should use term insert) in this table comparing values from curtest with prior value in prevtest?

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no concept of "last row" unless you have a column that specifies the ordering.

Comment: only one row is inserted at a time. so i don't think it will affect the order of previous data in `prevtest` table. it should always get inserted at the last. Correct me if i am wrong. any way i will have a column which will specify the order thanks.

Comment: `Correct me if i am wrong.` You are wrong. As @GordonLinoff already said: there is no implicit ordering in your table, so there is no `latest`

Answer (score 0):

You can always use [NON-Standard From](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-update.html) clause:

```
UPDATE Table2
SET column1 = Table1.column1,
  column2 = Table1.column2,
  column3 = Table1.column3
FROM Table1
WHERE Table1.id = Table2.id
```

Additionally, you can create a [trigger](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html) if you want.

Comment: Isn't that the same as mine ?

Comment: @Sagi I think this answer is different than your approach .. isn't it

Comment: Besides from the trigger?

Comment: Oh I see, you edit your answer, I didn't see that when I key in this answer. Sorry sagi you are so brilliant. XD

Answer (score 0):

You want to insert new rows, so `insert` is the right approach.  Let me assume that a column `curtestId` specifies the ordering:

```
insert into prevtest(data, value)
    select ct.data, ct.value
    from curtest ct left join
         (select distinct on (data) pt.*
          from prevtest pt
          order by pt.data, pt.curtestId desc
         ) pt
         on ct.data = pt.data
    where (ct.value is distinct from pt.value);
```

Note the use of `is distinct from` to handle `NULL` values.

For multiple columns, you would extend the `where` clause to handle all of them.

Comment: Data column will not be necessarily same in both table. here you are joining based  on data.  if `curtest` has any difference from the last row of `prevtest` data, i need to insert it.